# Recurrent neural layers in Keras

Tags: neural-network, keras

I'm learning neural networks through Keras and would like to explore my sequential dataset on a recurrent neural network.
I was [reading the docs](http://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) and trying to make sense of the [LSTM example](http://keras.io/examples/).

My questions are:

1. What are the `timesteps` that are required for both layers?
2. How do I prepare a sequential dataset that works with `Dense` as an input for those recurrent layers?
3. What does the `Embedding` layer do?

Comment: I'm also fairly new to LSTM's, especially in Keras, but I found this example to be very helpful: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_text_generation.py maybe it will help you too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Timesteps are a pretty bothering thing about Keras. Due to the fact that data you provide as an input to your LSTM must be a numpy array it is needed (at least for Keras version <= 0.3.3) to have a specified shape of data - even with a "time" dimension. You can only put a sequences which have a specified length as an input - and in case your inputs vary in a length - you should use either an artificial data to "fill" your sequences or use a "stateful" mode (please read carefully Keras documentation to understand what this approach means). Both solutions might be unpleasent - but it's a cost you pay that Keras is so simple :) I hope that in version 1.0.0 they will do something with that.
2. There are two ways to apply norecurrent layers after LSTM ones:

   - you could set an argument return_sequences to False - then only the last activations from every sequence will be passed to a "static" layer.
   - you could use one of "time distributed" layers - to get more flexibility with what you want to do with your data.
3. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182775/what-is-an-embedding-layer-in-a-neural-network :)